Refrain Mapstruct from considering Methods
I'm using Mapstruct to map between POJOs. Everything was fine until I added a few convenience methods to one of the classes. Now Mapstruct complains with error: Unmapped target properties: "..." with a list of the new method names.
I was surprised that Mapstruct even consideres the methods in the mapping (I cannot even imagine what "mapping methods" should mean), but even more so when I did not discover a good way of preventing it. One means I found was the very general unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE (which would also defeat the desired error when fields change).
A more specific way would be to add a @Mapping(target = "<methodname>", ignore = true). But as I understand it I would have to do this for every mapper interface method that involves the changed class, for every added method.
Is there a way to annotate the POJO methods themselves, like @MapStruct(ignore)? Or is there a way to tell Mapstruct not to try to map methods in general?
